# Does $L^p$ convergence imply convergence of integrals?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

If $L^p-\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} f_t = f$ ($p > 1$), is it the case that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int f_t^p = \int f^p$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the mean value theorem with the function $h(x) = x^p$, $x \ge 0$. If $a,b \ge 0$ there exists a point $c$ in between $a$ and $b$ with $$h(a) - h(b) = h'(c) (a-b)$$
and in particular
$$|a^p - b^p| = p c^{p-1} |a-b|.$$
But the function $x \mapsto x^{p-1}$ is monotone, so $c^{p-1}$ lies in between $a^{p-1}$ and $b^{p-1}$. This implies $c^{p-1} \le a^{p-1} + b^{p-1}$ so that we get the general inequality
$$ |a^p - b^p| \le p a^{p-1} |a-b| + p b^{p-1} |a-b|.$$
Now take $a = |f(x)|$ and $b = |f_t(x)|$ to get 
\begin{align*}\left| |f(x)|^p - |f_t(x)|^p \right| &\le p |f(x)|^{p-1} \big| |f(x)| - |f_t(x)| \big| + p|f_t(x)|^{p-1} \big| |f(x)| - |f_t(x)| \big| \\ &\le p |f(x)|^{p-1} \big|f(x) - f_t(x) \big| + p|f_t(x)|^{p-1} |f(x) - f_t(x)|.
\end{align*} 
Holder's inequality implies
$$\int |f(x)|^{p-1} \big| |f(x)| - |f_t(x)| \big| \le \|f\|_p^{p-1} \|f - f_t\|_p$$ and 
$$\int |f_t(x)|^{p-1} \big| |f(x)| - |f_t(x)| \big| \le \|f_t\|_p^{p-1} \|f - f_t\|_p.$$
Since $\|f_t\|_p^{p-1} \le 2^{p-1}(\|f\|_p^{p-1} + \|f - f_t\|_p^{p-1})$ you have
$$\int ||f(x)|^p - |f_t(x)|^p| \le p \|f\|_p\|f - f_t\|_p + p2^{p-1}(\|f\|_p^{p-1} + \|f - f_t\|_p^{p-1})\|f - f_t\|_p$$ which tends to $0$ as $t \to \infty$. Finally use $$ \left| \int |f|^p - \int |f_t|^p \right| \le \int ||f(x)|^p - |f_t(x)|^p| \to 0.$$

Comment: How does Holder's inequality imply
$$\int |f(x)|^{p-1} \big| |f(x)| - |f_t(x)| \big| \le \|f\|_p \|f - f_t\|_p$$ and 
$$\int |f_t(x)|^{p-1} \big| |f(x)| - |f_t(x)| \big| \le \|f_t\|_p \|f - f_t\|_p.$$

Comment: Compute the holder conjugate of $p$...

Comment: Why does $\|f_t\|_p^{p-1} \le 2^{p-1}(\|f\|_p^{p-1} + \|f - f_t\|_p^{p-1})$?

Comment: OK. Got it: $$\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^c\leq\left(\max(a,b)\right)^c\leq a^c+b^c$$ for $a,b,c\geq0$.